# Dependency management with maven profiles

Tags: maven

In the pom.xml for a library that is to be used as a dependency in upstream projects, we have specified dependencies as follows

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java17</id>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.fabric8.mq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mq-fabric</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <properties>
                <java-version>1.7</java-version>
            </properties>

        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>java16</id>

            <properties>
                <java-version>1.6</java-version>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
                    <version>5.10.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
                    <version>5.10.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

However the transitive dependencies in the upstream projects are not as expected i.e even when we include the version built with java-version 1.6 we see mq-fabric as the dependency